# Install fancyimpute in conda, getting "PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels"

Tags: python, installation, package, anaconda, fancyimpute

I successfully install the fancyimpute in my env but the package still shows missing in the current channel, not sure what this means. 
I tried pip install fancyimpute  + conda search fancyimpute, it shows the same error as below: Any idea how to fix this. Appreciate it!

```
(py36) C:\Users\chenl>conda install -c brittainhard fancyimpute
Fetching package metadata ...............

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - fancyimpute

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/brittainhard/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/brittainhard/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're in Windows, and the brittainhard/fancyimpute doesn't have a Windows version available. To get a Windows version, you'll need to use one of the other [conda channels](https://anaconda.org/search?q=fancyimpute), for example [CIMCB/fancyimpute](https://anaconda.org/cimcb/fancyimpute): `conda install -c cimcb fancyimpute`

Answer (score 0):

Try to install running this commands in this order:

```
conda install ecos  
conda install CVXcanon  
pip install fancyimpute
```